# Change hover colour in Vuetify 3

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my AppBar.vue component of my Vuetify 3 project, the hamburger icon and menu items have a very dark hover effect on them.

In the docs, the default hover is a light grey not full black, does anyone know why this has happened and how I can change it, please?

I've tried several CSS selectors and pseudo selectors including adding !important, and wrapping the element in v-hover set to disabled...

[image: hover items]

[image: hover icon]

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar :elevation="2">
      <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-v-on -->

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"> </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-app-bar-title>The Candidate Consultants</v-app-bar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          class="custom-hover"
          v-for="item in menuItems"
          :key="item.title"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

One of the CSS selectors I tried:

```css
@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
.custom-hover:hover {
  background-color: $blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this happens when there is no theme, not sure why it happens in your example.

The hover change is set on an element with the `*__overlay` class and it is defined by its opacity, which is set through the variables `--v-hover-opacity` and `--v-theme-overlay-multiplier`, i.e.:

```css
v-list-item:hover > .v-list-item__overlay {
  opacity: calc(var(--v-hover-opacity)*var(--v-theme-overlay-multiplier));
}
```

The variables should be provided by the theme:

```css
.v-theme--light{
  --v-hover-opacity: 0.04;
  --v-theme-overlay-multiplier: 1;
}
```

You could (re-)set them yourself, but I would rather figure out what is wrong with your theme. Do you have an idea what that might be?

Note that if I put your code into a snippet, it works as expected:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      drawer: ref(true),
      menuItems: ref([{title: 'item 1'}, {title: 'item 2'}])
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar :elevation="2">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"> </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-app-bar-title>The Candidate Consultants</v-app-bar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          class="custom-hover"
          v-for="item in menuItems"
          :key="item.title"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
  
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks that resolved the issue! I added a theme to my vuetify.ts and the code in your 2nd snippet to main.scss and it's fixed. Legend :)

Comment: That's great! With the theme, do you still need the 2nd snippet though? It's weird if the variables are not provided by the theme.

Comment: thanks again for the help Moritz!

can you please clarify which files your two code snippets above should be added to? 

when I refer to adding a theme, I added this code to my vuetify.ts

`import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import (etc...)

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: "light",
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: "#6200ee",
          secondary: "#03dac6",
          accent: "#ff4081",
        },
      },
      dark: {etc...}

export default vuetify;`

Comment: If it works it works, that's great! It's just confusing that you apparently have to add the `light` theme yourself. This should be provided from Vuetify CSS. If you hadn't accidentally [disabled the theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#disable-theme), I don't understand why those values weren't there. But unless you run into more issues, I guess all is well. Nice!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue reported and only by forcing the css the hover gets fixed. I think it could be some issue in vuetify when you add custom themes (it loses the information from default) or something like that

Answer (score 5):

So I was facing this very issue along with other on the theme department and what was missing was actually :

```
import 'vuetify/styles';
```

In my vuetify.ts file I create the themes and options to inject into useVuetify. For some reason this import is not easy to be found in the docs.

This changed the whole layout to behave as it should (not only hover but everything)

Answer (score 1):

Styling the `v-list-item__overlay` class will set the primary color that the opacity is then applied to:

```
<style lang="scss">
   .v-list-item__overlay {
      background-color: theme("colors.primary.500") !important;
   }
</style>
```

And if you are using